# FILTER_SANITIZE_URL, keeping spaces?

Tags: php

From what I understand, after getting (`$_GET`) the url, the %20's are already converted to spaces. So if I then use the `filter_var($url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL)` function, it removes the already converted spaces.

How do I go around this, and still use the above function?

Or should I just use `str_replace()` ? Although that doesn't seem to work in combination with `filter_var($url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL)`.

Answer (score 1):

One way to keep using FILTER_SANITIZE_URL keeping spaces, is to replace spaces first with two allowed characters unlikely to occur next to each other, then replace replace them back to spaces afterwards.

e.g.

```
str_replace('\/', ' ', filter_var(str_replace(' ', '\/', $url), FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
```

NB: Not exactly exactly sure `\/` is the best candidate for that. But I have used it in a safe context.

Answer (score 0):

You can use urlencode($url) before you call filter_var.

Why are you trying to filter the $url?

Comment: To sanitize possible bad user input. Example: app/users/edit/John%20Doe. Using urlencode() before filter_var, I need to correct it on another place, because then spaces are +'s.

Comment: `str_replace(' ', '%20', $url)` before `filter_var()` won't even work. And it seems pretty straightforward to me, to solve it. But it won't.

Answer (score 0):

So I am assuming in this case that `$url` is derived from `$_GET['url']` (or some or query string parameter) directly without any other modification before using in `filter_var`?

If these URL's are going to have spaces in them, you might want to work directly with the raw query string which is available in `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`.  Of course this means you need to need to manually parse out the parameter you are looking for (perhaps using `explode('&')` - don't use `parse_str()` as it will do the same conversoin done for `$_GET()`)

Comment: Exactly. And isn't it better to just use `str_replace()`, instead of `explode()`?

Comment: I meant use `explode('&')` to get to the portion of the query string you are interested in.  So if you had a query string like `url=something&param1=somethingelse&param2=somethingtotalltdifferent` You could explode the raw query string to get at your value.  Of course you could also use regex or other string manipulation to get at the parameter you are interested in.

Comment: Ah yes, but I'm already using SEO friendly urls with all the slashes. And I'm already exploding those. It's just that I want to keep my spaces in my url values, while using the `filter_var()` to also sanitize it. Example: app/users/edit/John%20Doe

Answer (score 0):

This is an equivalent of `FILTER_SANITIZE_URL` plus a space:

```
$value = preg_replace("/[^\x20-\x7E]/", "", $value);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `%20`s in your URL should ***not*** be converted to spaces, because they're part of your original value. If they are being decoded, that means you failed to correctly *encode* the value during transport in the URL.

Value you want to transport in a URL:

```
My string with spaces & special characters
```

In a URL, this must be encoded to:

```
My%20string%20with%20spaces%20%26%20special%20characters
```

Final URL:

```
http://example.com?foo=My%20string%20with%20spaces%20%26%20special%20characters
```

This is the value you want to transport as query parameter in a URL. Which means you need to encode *it* properly to:

```
http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%3Ffoo%3DMy%2520string%2520with%2520spaces%2520%2526%2520special%2520characters
```

Final final URL:

```
http://my-service.example.com?url=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%3Ffoo%3DMy%2520string%2520with%2520spaces%2520%2526%2520special%2520characters
```

PHP will decode this *once* and in `$_GET['url']` you will find:

```
http://example.com?foo=My%20string%20with%20spaces%20%26%20special%20characters
```